# How to rotate text without being limited to degrees divisible by 90?

Tags: css, text, rotation

In a small website I have a paragraph (`<p>text here</p>`) and I want to make it rotate "slightly" (like 15 degrees to the left or right), but all "text rotation" examples that I found on the internet only work with numbers that are divisible by 90.
Does anyone have a solution that gives me more freedom in choosing how much to rotate stuff?

Comment: `transform: rotate(15deg);` in css for this element. If you want more detailed answer provide us with code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transform` property can be applied with degrees of rotation.

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-15deg); /* Supports negative values too! */

  /* Legacy vendor support for different browsers. */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);   /* IE */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);   /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);   /* Safari */
  -o-transform: rotate(-15deg);   /* Opera */
}
```

```html
<p class="rotate">This is my text displayed at an offset of 15 degrees!</p>
```